# Hapijs SaaS multi Tenant Referene Example

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant, hapi.js, saas

I am trying to build a multi tenant SaaS application with HapiJS and MongoDB. I would like to achieve the following:

- Each tenant has a unique URL
- I would determine a tenant from the URL
- Same code base for all tenants launched with different configuration, and each tenant runs on different node process
- Each tenant has separate database

Is there a reference example/application I can use for direction?

Comment: Did you find any solutions / examples ?